# Redirect not working in JSF Primefaces

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF Primefaces Web App that has needs to be redirected to Login page when the session expires.

```
if (session == null)
{
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/Login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
}
```

But after the time out, the page is not redirecting and if I do a refresh, it redirects with the redirect=true. How can I overcome this?

My directory structure is

-Login.xhtml

-app/index.xhtml

-app/settings.xhtml

Below is my web.xml :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        1
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<filter>
    <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.web.app.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: What if there was no session and I couldn't access the external context object too? @BalusC . I have added the web.xml bro. Could you help me solve this? Breaking my head for 2 days now

Comment: could you elaborate on web sockets part? also can this be checker kinda function that is fired when any event occurs on the client and there it checks for the session and redirects if there is no session?

Comment: client event checking is not able to redirect the page for some reason. even response.sendRedirect("www.google.com") doesn't work

Comment: What if the user made some mouse moves and that didn't make any requests to the Tomcat server, this means that the idle time out would be reset every now and then as he moves the mouse as well the tomcat session will expire since there is no request made. What can I do now?